# Usage of "representation" in the sense of being part of a group

Tags: meaning-in-context, nouns, connotation

Is the following sentence correct and clear?

> "Elite universities in England are under constant scrutiny because of the low representation of certain population groups, particularly state-school pupils from disadvantaged backgrounds."

The meaning should be that elite universities are scrutinized because they admit disproportionately few students from some population groups. Somehow I feel that 'representation' requires clarifying the reference group – like "...low representation of certain population groups **in admissions**,...". But that also sounds strange to me.

Comment: If your question is whether the sentence is correct and clear, then yes it absolutely is correct and clear.

Comment: All students at a university have been *admitted* to the university (have gone through "admissions", as you emphasize).  Therefore, unless you are specifically trying to distinguish between students and staff, any reference to 'admissions' is superfluous; and if you *are* trying to distinguish between students and staff, then there are clearer ways of doing it.

Comment: @TrevorD: I would rather like to avoid confusion with representation in *applications* as opposed to admissions (not staff vs. students). But it seems from what you say that the most natural meaning of representation in this context is indeed admissions.

Comment: It didn't occur to me that you might be referring to *applications*, so clearly "admissions" is implied; but, for added clarity, you could put "the low *student* representation".

Comment: Personally, I'd delete the word "the" (before "low") and add the word "their" in its place. "Elite universities . . . because of their . . .." As @TrevorD suggested, by adding the word "student" before "representation," you clarify the segment of the universities you are focusing on. Don

Comment: The sentence is correct and clear to me but, if you wanted to make a distinction between students and staff, you could replace 'in admissions' with 'in the student body' since @TrevorD said all students have gone through the admissions process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As various commenters have noted beneath the original question,

> Elite universities in England are under constant scrutiny because of the low representation of certain population groups, particularly state-school pupils from disadvantaged backgrounds.

clearly intends "representation" to mean "number [of members of one or more demographic groups] in the school relative to their number in the outside population."

Because the last part of the sentence specifically refers to "state-school pupils from disadvantaged backgrounds," we may infer that the focus here is on students at elite universities and not on, say, professors and instructors at elite universities. That is, we could restate the sense of the sentence as

> Elite universities in England are under constant scrutiny because of low representation of certain population groups in the student body, particularly state-school pupils from disadvantaged backgrounds.

But we could easily apply the notion of "representation" to professors or others, instead of to students, if that were our intention:

> Elite universities in England are under constant scrutiny because of low representation of certain population groups in the ranks of professors and instructors, particularly individuals who began as state-school pupils from disadvantaged backgrounds.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is perfectly clear. That is, if you meant to say that certain groups of people are not admitted as often as others.